# Hands-On Matlab Resources for Wireless Networks Modeling using Stochastic Geometry

Tags: stochastic-processes, geometric-probability, point-processes

[Stochastic Geometry](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=stochastic%20geometry&btnG=&oq=stoc) has become a very strong mathematical tool for studying and understanding several aspects of wireless communication and networks. As I write this, I find quite a large number of recently published research articles [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?newsearch=true&queryText=stochastic%20geometry).

Are there any resources especially hands-on Matlab files to understand how this area is modeled? I know only of [survey papers](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=stochastic%20geometry%20survey%20tutorial%20wireless%20networks&btnG=) and books. It would be highly appreciated if anyone knows such links or willing to share such files.